# The faces of $n$ unit cubes have been painted either black or white at random.

Tags: combinatorics

The faces of $n$ unit cubes have been painted either black or white at random. What is the probability that these cubes can be lined up to make a 'white train' , an $1 \times 1 \times n$ box which only white faces are visible ? I have found that for the middle cubes will need $6C6+6C5+6C4+6C3$ possible arrangements and there are a total of $2^{64}$ TOTAL arrangements .

What is tough is how to find the 'ends' or how many arrangements will result in the ends of this 'train' being white too. I computed $24$ ways since for each face there are $4 \times 6$ ways.

Comment: Are the randomly coloured cubes arranged randomly in a line, or are we only figuring out the probability that the randomly coloured cubes *can* be arranged to form a 'white train'? Your question states the latter but your working suggests you have assumed the former since you seem to be talking about arrangements.

Comment: as i wrote the probability they *can* be which means we can rotate them ect but must form a 'white train'

Answer (score 4):

***Note: The following calculation is for a $1\times n$ train with all 6 faces white.***

---

**Method 1: Elementary Counting**

Firstly assume each cube can have either:

1. No black faces ($1$ colouring)
2. $1$ black face ($6$ colourings)
3. $2$ opposite black faces ($3$ colourings)

then, as there are $n$ cubes there are $(1+6+3)^n=10^n$ colourings of types 1, 2 and 3.

However, we have *over counted* since there are, amongst our $10^n$ colourings, $3^n$ colourings that have exactly $n$ cubes with $2$ opposite black faces, and $\binom{n}{1}\cdot (6+1)\cdot 3^{n-1}$ colourings that have exactly $n-1$ cubes with $2$ opposite black faces.

Subtract these to give

$$10^n-3^n-7n\cdot 3^{n-1}$$

colourings which allow us to form a white train.

Since each cube has $6$ faces, each cube has $2^6$ total possible colourings. Then, as there are $n$ cubes, there are $2^{6n}$ total colourings *of all the $n$ cubes*, so the probability of being able to form a white train is:

$$\frac{10^n-3^n-7n\cdot 3^{n-1}}{2^{6n}}\tag{Answer}$$

**Method 2: Using Exponential Generating Functions**

I orginally formulated the problem in terms of exponential generating functions (*egfs*). For completeness here is what I did:

Formulate an *egf* for cube colourings with $0$ ($z_0$) or $1$ ($z_1$) black face. There must be at least $2$ of these so it's *egf* is:

$$\frac{1}{2!}(z_0+6z_1)^2+\frac{1}{3!}(z_0+6z_1)^3+\frac{1}{4!}(z_0+6z_1)^4+\cdots=e^{z_0+6z_1}-(z_0+6z_1)-1$$

Next formulate an *egf* for cube colourings with $2$ opposite black faces ($z_2$). There can be any number of these so we have it's *egf*:

$$1+\frac{1}{1!}(3z_2)+\frac{1}{2!}(3z_2)^2+\frac{1}{3!}(3z_2)^3+\cdots=e^{3z_2}$$

Multiply these together to give our *egf* that enumerates valid colourings

$$(e^{z_0+6z_1}-(z_0+6z_1)-1)e^{3z_2}$$

where the coefficient of $z_0^{k_0}z_1^{k_1}z_2^{k_2}$ tells us the number of valid colourings with $k_0$ all white cubes, $k_1$ cubes with $1$ black face and $k_2$ cubes with $2$ opposite black faces.

We are only interested in enumerating according to the total number of cubes so we need not distinguish $z_0$, $z_1$ and $z_2$: put $z_0=z_1=z_2=z$ then the desired *egf* is now:

$$(e^{7z}-7z-1)e^{3z}=e^{10z}-7ze^{3z}-e^{3z}$$

and taking the $z^n/n!$ coefficient gives us the desired count for valid colourings:

$$[z^n/n!](e^{10z}-7ze^{3z}-e^{3z})=10^n-7n\cdot 3^{n-1}-3^n$$

as before. Which then leads to the same probability.

Comment: I didn't read your whole solution, but it seems to go wrong at the beginning.  The middle cubes in the train could have 3 black faces:  one facing the table and two opposite vertical faces hidden by the adjacent cubes.  Does this need to be fixed accordingly?   I might have misunderstood what you mean.

Comment: yes the middle cubes need either 6C6 , 6C5, 6C4, or 6C3 faces painted white . this gives the number of arrangements needed even for the 3 faces white rule which you are correct . these are added up to divide by 2^6 =64 total arrangments . The attack above is spurious . the part thats not eay and I still havent nailed down is how to figure in the 'end cubes' which Need at least 4 faces white ( do you see why?)

Comment: @fredgoodman, I see no mention of a table in the question so I calculated for a $1\times n$ train that is white on *all* the outside faces.

Comment: @RandinD. The middle cubes cannot have *all* $\binom{6}{3}$ colourings of 3 white, 3 black faces. Take, for example, a colouring where all 3 faces surrounding a corner are white, this leaves the diagonally opposite corner surrounded by black faces. There is no orientation of such a cube that will display only white faces when in a train, even *if* the train is resting on a surface. In addition, there are $2^6=64$ colourings for *each cube* so that needs raising to the power $n$ for $n$ cubes.

Comment: i fixed it ..yes the denominator needed to be to a n power thanks ..i saw when I reread the first solution above

Comment: and yes then it would be 6c3 minus the arrangements that u point out which is how many? I figured that each corner has such a coloring and third are 8 vertices or corners so minus 8

Comment: @RandinMichaelDivelbiss. That's right, there are ${}^6\text{C}_3-8$ three-colourings of the middle cubes (this is what I did in my *other* answer here). Of course, it's not quite that simple because any $n-2$  of the $n$ cubes could be the middle cubes and then there are the colourings of the 2 end cubes to consider, some of which are the same as the middle cube colourings e.g. A colouring of two adjacent black faces would suit both an end cube and a middle cube.

Comment: ah that's the one last ' trick ' I didn't see . i will have to edit my formula . either way it seems so messy doesn't it ?

Comment: i still dont get this part "there are, amongst our 10n colourings, 3n colourings that have exactly n cubes with 2 opposite black faces, and (n1)⋅(6+1)⋅3n−1 colourings that have exactly n−1 cubes with 2 opposite black faces" N.shales  maybe u can explain more ? not that I doubt it's true just that I'm not getting it

Comment: Sure. There are 10 different colourings in the bullet points *per cube*. So that's $10^n$ colourings being considered as there are $n$ cubes, but some of those will have *all* the cubes with 2 opposite black faces, there are 3 colourings per cube with 2 opposite faces black so that's $3^n$ colourings where all $n$ cubes have 2 opposite black faces. We subtract these from the $10^n$ colourings under consideration. We also subtract colourings where exactly $1$ cube has fewer than 0 or 1 red face, there are 7 colourings of 1 such cube and $3^{n-1}$ of the rest, we choose the 1 cube in $n$ ways.

Comment: I still don't get that part .maybe u can send pic or diagram to my gmail ?

Comment: @RandinMichaelDivelbiss. I would be happy to do that.

Comment: thanks,  do i teach @ a school- college or university? my gmail is randindivelbiss@gmail.com

Comment: @RandinMichaelDivelbiss, no I don't teach but have done in the past. I have emailed you so you might want to remove your email address now, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

***Note: The following calculation is for a $1\times n$ train resting on a surface with $5$ visible sides white.***

---

**Here I present an elementary counting method only**

Assume each cube has either:

1. All white faces ($1$ colouring)
2. $1$ black face ($6$ colourings)
3. $2$ black faces ($\binom{6}{2}=15$ colorings)
4. $3$ black faces not all adjacent to a single corner ($\binom{6}{3}-8=12$ colorings)

There are therfore $(1+6+15+12)^n=34^n$ colourings of type 1,2,3 and 4.

We have over counted, though, because amongst these $34^n$ colourings there are $(12+3)^n=15^n$ where *all* $n$ cubes have $3$ black faces (described by 4 above) or $2$ *opposite* black faces ($3$ of the $15$ described by 2 above).

Also, amongst the $34^n$ there are $\binom{n}{1}\cdot (12+6+1)\cdot 15^{n-1}$ colourings where exactly $n-1$ cubes have $3$ black faces (described by 4 above) or $2$ *opposite* black faces ($3$ of the $15$ described by 2 above) and *only* $1$ cube has either $2$ *adjacent* black faces ($12$ of the $15$ described by 2 above) or $1$ black face (described by 2 above) or all white faces (as described by 1 above).

Subtracting these two cases from $34^n$ gives valid colourings:

$$34^n-15^n-19n\cdot 15^{n-1}$$

and since there are $2^{6n}$ total colourings of $n$ cubes the desired probability is:

$$\frac{34^n-15^n-19n\cdot 15^{n-1}}{2^{6n}}\tag{Answer}$$

I will leave the generating function approach but it yields, in this case, an *egf* for valid colourings: $e^{34z}-19ze^{15z}-e^{15z}$.

Comment: when you say "5 white faces" dont you mean at least 7 ? the end cubes . and then it would be 7 + 3n faces white not 5 for a train

Comment: @RandinD. I meant the 5 visible sides *of the train*: 3 visible long sides along it's length and 1 at either end. The 1 long side in contact with the surface is obviously not visible. In fact I used the word "side" so as not to confuse with the "faces" of the individual cubes. If you want to count visible "faces" of cubes then there are $2$ at either end and $3n$ in the middle, that's $2+3n$, for $n$ cubes.

Comment: I wonder why my attack didn't work lol . are you saying it can't be solved by taking arrangements of white faces ? instead of black

Comment: @RandinMichaelDivelbiss. The approach you suggest is actually just the beginning of an approach. If you were to continue you would come to the same conclusion as me. Notice that $\binom{6}{6}+\binom{6}{5}+\binom{6}{4}+\binom{6}{3}-8=34$ is the number of colourings of a single cube described in my answer here. You would soon find that, using the same logic as my answer here, you would have to subtract some of those as some colorings of all the $n$ cubes do not allow any appropriate end cube colorings.

Answer (score 0):

this might be 1 solution. two end cubes have to have 
both two opposite faces white and two faces that share  an edge which there are 6 and 12 ways to paint these,on one cube so p(n)= [((6c6+6c5 6c4+6c3)n)/64+(2)(6)(12)/2^6n] . the train needs 2 end cubes as well .( starting with one middle cube after we have got the two end cubes is the first part)